How do I set selenium-side-runner to read cookies?
I record a test in Selenium IDE which takes login details from a cookie.
The test runs fine in Selenium IDE but using the command line SIDE Runner
it fails to fill in the login details & the test fails.
The only clue I've found is Selenium Webdriver needs something like this:
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--remote-debugging-port=9222")
selenium-side-runner -h
options are probably relevant ?
If I type the login details during record the actions are not recorded.
I could probably fix this but cookie reading in selenium-side-runner should be possible ?
